# Dynamic Parallelism - undefined reference to __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary linking error while compiling - separate compilation

Tags: cuda

I got a problem when I try to compile a simple code there are C++ and Cuda code compile in a separated way.

Here's my code

main.cpp:

```
#include "file.cuh"

int main( void )
{
     test();
     return 0;
}
```

file.cuh:

```
void test( void );
```

file.cu:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cstdio>

#include "file.cuh"

__global__ void printId( void )
{
    printf("Hello from block %d \n", blockIdx.x);
}

__global__ void DynPara( void )
{
    dim3 grid( 2, 1, 1 );
    dim3 block( 1, 1, 1 );

    printId<<< grid, block >>>();
}

void test( void )
{
    dim3 grid( 1, 1, 1 );
    dim3 block( 1, 1, 1 );

    dynPara<<< grid, block >>>();
}
```

I compile with:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -lcudadevrt -rdc=true -c file.cu
g++ file.o main.cpp -L<path> -lcudart
```

And here's the error while compiling:

```
file.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_39_tmpxft_00005b2f_00000000_6_file_cpp1_ii_99181f96()':
tmpxft_00005b2f_00000000-3_file.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_00005b2f_00000000_6_file_cpp1_ii_99181f96'
```

- os: Red Hat
- card: K20x

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This question is pretty much a duplicate of this [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076052/cuda-dynamic-parallelism-makefile).

Dynamic parallelism requires relocatable device code *linking*, in addition to compiling.

Your `nvcc` command line specifies a compile-only operation (`-rdc=true -c`).

`g++` does not do any device code linking.  So in a scenario like this, when doing the final link operation using `g++` [an extra device code link step](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#examples) is required.

Something like this:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -c file.cu
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dlink -o file_link.o file.o -lcudadevrt -lcudart
g++ file.o file_link.o main.cpp -L<path> -lcudart -lcudadevrt
```

Answer (score 10):

When using CMake, setting `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION` before `find_package()` enables both relocatable device code compiling and linking:

```
SET(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
find_package(CUDA QUIET REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this made no difference to me. I had to use the [`CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION.html) property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, sorry for my low reputation, I can't comment under `Robert Crovella`'s answer directly
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22116121/14377278

Just like his command, but I need link cuda library when use `nvcc` and `nvlink` to compile and link, like below

```sh
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -c file.cu -L<path>
nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dlink -o file_link.o file.o -lcudadevrt -lcudart -L<path>
g++ file.o file_link.o main.cpp -L<path> -lcudart -lcudadevrt
```