# Dynamic Parallelism - separate compilation: undefined reference to __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary

Tags: cuda, icc, dynamic-parallelism

Although I have followed apendix C "Compiling Dynamic Parallelism" from "CUDA Programming Guide" and the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115197/dynamic-parallelism-undefined-reference-to-cudaregisterlinkedbinary-linking), I cannot manage to solve the problem I have. After the compilation and linking (make DivideParalelo) I get the following error:

```html
./build/metodos.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_42_tmpxft_00002599_00000000_6_metodos_cpp1_ii_32c9141e()':
tmpxft_00002599_00000000-3_metodos.cudafe1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_42_tmpxft_00002599_00000000_6_metodos_cpp1_ii_32c9141e'
./build/GPUutil.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_42_tmpxft_000025c0_00000000_6_GPUutil_cpp1_ii_f81fb8b5()':
tmpxft_000025c0_00000000-3_GPUutil.cudafe1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_42_tmpxft_000025c0_00000000_6_GPUutil_cpp1_ii_f81fb8b5'
./build/PCA_Kernels.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_46_tmpxft_000025e6_00000000_6_PCA_Kernels_cpp1_ii_8a59b72a()':
tmpxft_000025e6_00000000-3_PCA_Kernels.cudafe1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x15): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_46_tmpxft_000025e6_00000000_6_PCA_Kernels_cpp1_ii_8a59b72a'
./build/DivideParalelo.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_49_tmpxft_0000260c_00000000_6_DivideParalelo_cpp1_ii_16d0a16f()':
tmpxft_0000260c_00000000-3_DivideParalelo.cudafe1.cpp:(.text.startup+0x385): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_49_tmpxft_0000260c_00000000_6_DivideParalelo_cpp1_ii_16d0a16f'
make: *** [DivideParalelo] Error 1
```

A simplified version of my code is listed below.

**DivideParalelo.cu**:

```css
#include <stdio.h> #include <string.h>
/*C includes*/

extern"C" {
  #include"io.h"
  #include"util.h"
}
/* CUDA includes*/

#include"cuda.h" 
#include"cublas.h" 
#include"metodos.h" 
#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(value) {
 /...
}
 #define DIM 100
    /*
 * image
 * num_bands
 * columns initially is lines_samples, later the number of endmembers
 */
    __global__ void Divide(double *image, int num_bands, int columns, int DIM_MIN, int numColsLastPiece, double *out, double *piece) {
      int tid=threadIdx.x; //col
      int bid=blockIdx.x; //row
      for (int tile=0;tile<(columns -1)/ DIM_MIN +1;tile++) {
          __shared__ double sh_piece[DIM]; 
         //some code here...
        __syncthreads();
        }
        int mat=HYSIME(piece,columns,num_bands);
      }
    }
    int main(int argc,
    char** argv) {
      //load file (argv[1]) with the image into dMt 
      //...
      //Allocate GPU memory:
      double *devicedM, *deviceOut;
      CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMalloc((void**)&devicedM, num_bands*lines_samples*sizeof(double)));
      CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceOut, num_bands*lines_samples*sizeof(double)));
      //here the call to the kernel
    }
```

**metodos.cu**:

```html
extern "C"{
 #include "util.h"
    #include "io.h"
}
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cublas.h"
#include "PCA_Kernels.h"
#include "GPUutil.h"
#include <stdio.h>
 __device__ __host__ int HYSIME(double *M, int lines_samples, int num_bands){
 int N_END =0;
 double *y;
 double *w;
 double *Rw;
 
 y = (double*) malloc(lines_samples * num_bands * sizeof(double));
 //changed to implement calloc in the device:
 w = (double*) malloc(lines_samples * num_bands*sizeof(double));
 memset (w,0,lines_samples * num_bands);
 Rw = (double*) malloc(num_bands * num_bands* sizeof(double));
 memset (Rw,0,num_bands * num_bands);
    //some additional code here
 estNoise(y, w, Rw, num_bands, lines_samples);//GPUutil.cu
 return(N_END);
}
```

**GPUutil.cu**:

```css
#include "cublas.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
__device__ __host__  int destAdditiveNoise(double *r, double *w, double *Rw, int L, int N){

       //the code
 return (0);

}
   
 __device__ __host__ int estNoise(double *y, double *w, double *Rw, int L, int N){

    //the code
 return (0);
}

__device__ __host__ int hysime(double *y, double *w, double *Rw, int L, int N){ //L is num_bands N is lines_samples

    //the code
 return(0);
 
}
```

**Makefile**:

```css
MKL =1


#initial definitions (library paths et al.)
CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5
MKLROOT=/home/emartel/intel/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mkl
BUILD_DIR=./build

####################
#includes
#################### 
#Cuda includes
CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR=-I. -I$(CUDA_PATH)/include 
#-I$(SDK)/C/common/inc

#BLAS includes
BLAS_INCLUDE_DIR=-I. -I$(MKLROOT)/include


####################
#library search paths
####################
CUDA_LIB_DIR=-L$(CUDA_PATH)/lib64 
#-L$(SDK)/C/lib -L$(SDK)/C/common/lib/linux
BLAS_LIB_DIR=-L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64  -L$(MKLROOT)/../compiler/lib/intel64 


####################
#libraries
####################
CUDALIBS=-lcublas -lcudart 
#-lcutil 
#-lGL -lGLU
utilS=  -lpthread  -lm 


####################
#other compilation flags
####################
CFLAGS= -Wwrite-strings
#-Wall
#-g


MKLFLAGS=-D __MKL
#sergio CUDAFLAGS= --gpu-architecture sm_30
#changed with sm_35
CUDAFLAGS= -arch=sm_35 
LINKERFLAGS= -Wl,--start-group $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a $(MKLROOT)/../compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.a -Wl,--end-group


####################
#utilities 
####################
io.o : io.c
 icc $(CFLAGS) -c -O3 io.c -o $(BUILD_DIR)/io.o

#BLAS and LAPACK wrapper
util.o : util.c
 icc $(CFLAGS) $(MKLFLAGS) $(BLAS_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 util.c -o $(BUILD_DIR)/util.o

#changed with rdec and -lcudadevrt: 
metodos.o : metodos.cu 
 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 -rdc=true metodos.cu -lcudadevrt -o $(BUILD_DIR)/metodos.o 


##################################
# PCA files
##################################
#changed with rdec and -lcudadevrt: 
GPUutil.o: GPUutil.cu
 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 -rdc=true GPUutil.cu -lcudadevrt -o $(BUILD_DIR)/GPUutil.o  
#changed with rdec and -lcudadevrt: 
PCA_Kernels.o: PCA_Kernels.cu
 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3  -rdc=true PCA_Kernels.cu -lcudadevrt -o $(BUILD_DIR)/PCA_Kernels.o 
#changed with rdec and -lcudadevrt: 
DivideParalelo.o: DivideParalelo.cu
 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 -rdc=true DivideParalelo.cu -lcudadevrt -o $(BUILD_DIR)/DivideParalelo.o 
 
#everything is already compiled, this is just a call to the linker
DivideParalelo: io.o util.o metodos.o GPUutil.o PCA_Kernels.o DivideParalelo.o
 icc $(CFLAGS) $(BUILD_DIR)/io.o $(BUILD_DIR)/util.o $(BUILD_DIR)/metodos.o $(BUILD_DIR)/GPUutil.o $(BUILD_DIR)/PCA_Kernels.o $(BUILD_DIR)/DivideParalelo.o $(CUDA_LIB_DIR) $(BLAS_LIB_DIR) $(LINKERFLAGS) $(utilS) $(CUDALIBS)  -o DivideParalelo 
####################
#misc
####################
clean:
 rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o  ./DivideParalelo
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Perhaps I misunderstood the separate compilation for dynamic parallelism.

Comment: You don't appear to have a device linkage step anywhere in you makefile. The section on separate compilation in the nvcc manual explains *exactly* how to do this. I recommend you read it.

Comment: Many thanks!!! I have already solved it.

Comment: Then add your solution as an answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem changing both compilation and linking of each cu file.

**Makefile:**

---

```html
MKL =1


#initial definitions (library paths et al.)
CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-6.5
MKLROOT=/home/emartel/intel/composer_xe_2015.0.090/mkl
BUILD_DIR=./build

####################
#includes
#################### 
#Cuda includes
CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR=-I. -I$(CUDA_PATH)/include 

#BLAS includes
BLAS_INCLUDE_DIR=-I. -I$(MKLROOT)/include


####################
#library search paths
####################
CUDA_LIB_DIR=-L$(CUDA_PATH)/lib64 
BLAS_LIB_DIR=-L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64  -L$(MKLROOT)/../compiler/lib/intel64 


####################
#libraries
####################
CUDALIBS=-lcublas -lcudart 

utilS=  -lpthread  -lm 


####################
#other compilation flags
####################
CFLAGS= -Wwrite-strings
MKLFLAGS=-D __MKL
CUDAFLAGS= -arch=sm_35 
LINKERFLAGS= -Wl,--start-group $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a $(MKLROOT)/../compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.a -Wl,--end-group

####################
#utilities 
####################
io.o : io.c
 icc $(CFLAGS) -c -O3 io.c -o $(BUILD_DIR)/io.o

#BLAS and LAPACK wrapper
util.o : util.c
 icc $(CFLAGS) $(MKLFLAGS) $(BLAS_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 util.c -o $(BUILD_DIR)/util.o

metodos.o : metodos.cu 
 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 -dc metodos.cu -o $(BUILD_DIR)/metodos.o

##################################
# PCA files
##################################
GPUutil.o: GPUutil.cu
 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 -dc GPUutil.cu -o $(BUILD_DIR)/GPUutil.o
    
PCA_Kernels.o: PCA_Kernels.cu
 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 -dc PCA_Kernels.cu -o $(BUILD_DIR)/PCA_Kernels.o  

DivideParalelo.o: DivideParalelo.cu
  nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -c -O3 -dc DivideParalelo.cu -o $(BUILD_DIR)/DivideParalelo.o
 
DivideParalelo: io.o util.o metodos.o GPUutil.o PCA_Kernels.o DivideParalelo.o
 nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR) -dlink $(BUILD_DIR)/io.o $(BUILD_DIR)/util.o $(BUILD_DIR)/metodos.o $(BUILD_DIR)/GPUutil.o $(BUILD_DIR)/PCA_Kernels.o $(BUILD_DIR)/DivideParalelo.o -lcudadevrt -o $(BUILD_DIR)/link.o
 icc $(CFLAGS) $(BUILD_DIR)/io.o $(BUILD_DIR)/util.o $(BUILD_DIR)/metodos.o $(BUILD_DIR)/GPUutil.o $(BUILD_DIR)/PCA_Kernels.o $(BUILD_DIR)/DivideParalelo.o $(BUILD_DIR)/link.o -lcudadevrt $(CUDA_LIB_DIR) $(BLAS_LIB_DIR) $(LINKERFLAGS) $(utilS) $(CUDALIBS)  -o DivideParalelo -lcudart  
####################
#misc
####################
clean:
 rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o ./DivideParalelo
```