# CMakeLists / relocatable device linking step (cudaRegisterLinkedBinary errors)

Tags: cmake, cuda

Even after listing and trying to link against the CUDA libraries in the CMakeLists, there are errors of "undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary...".

A previous question suggested to perform "**relocatable device code linking**" ([See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115197/dynamic-parallelism-undefined-reference-to-cudaregisterlinkedbinary-linking/41100906)) since  relocatable device code is necessary in this compilation. Is there a way to perform the relocatable device code linking through CMake (aka CMakeLists commands)?

CMake: **3.9.6** 
CUDA: **9.0** 
GCC/G++: **7.1.0** 
Ubuntu **16.04**

**Edit:** Adding the CMakeLists.txt

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(sigma_cuda_pkg)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "/usr/bin/nvcc")
set(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/cuda-9.0)
set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

find_package(CUDA 9.0 REQUIRED)

set(LIB_TYPE STATIC)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}; -arch=sm_61 -rdc=true -lcudart -lcudadevrt -lcuda)

find_library(SIGMA_LIBRARY sigma HINTS /lib)

file(GLOB SOURCES_SIGMA_C "src/*.c")
file(GLOB SOURCES_SIGMA_CPP "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB SOURCES_SIGMA_CUDA "src/*.cu")


include_directories(
include
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include
/usr/include/eigen3
)

CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
include
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include
/usr/include/eigen3
)

CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(sigma_cuda_pkg_lib  ${LIB_TYPE} ${SOURCES_SIGMA_C} ${SOURCES_SIGMA_CPP} ${SOURCES_SIGMA_CUDA})


CUDA_COMPILE(SIGMA_MAIN_CU_O src/main.cu OPTIONS -G)
CUDA_COMPILE(SIGMA_A_CU_O src/alpha.cu OPTIONS -G)
CUDA_COMPILE(SIGMA_A_ERROR_CU_O src/alpha_errors.cu OPTIONS -G)
CUDA_COMPILE(SIGMA_A_COMPARE_CU_O src/alpha_compare.cu OPTIONS -G)

CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(sigma_cuda_pkg_node src/main.cu ${SIGMA_A_CU_O} ${SIGMA_A_ERROR_CU_O} ${SIGMA_A_COMPARE_CU_O} OPTIONS -G)
set_target_properties(sigma_cuda_pkg_node PROPERTIES CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS ON)

target_link_libraries(
sigma_cuda_pkg_node 
sigma_cuda_pkg_lib
m
${CUDA_LIBRARIES} 
)
```

Multiple Resulting Errors with the following format:

```
undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_43_tmpxft_0000081d_00000000_6_sigmaB_cpp1_ii_633f8803'
```

Comment: [The second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43313147/3440745) to the referenced question addresses specifically CMake users. Have you tried what it suggests? (Setting `SET(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)`).

Comment: I tried the setting mentioned. No go.

Comment: Well, so it is time to show your code with that attempt (setting `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION`). Make sure that you have tried **clean configuration** (with empty build directory). Also, if you use `make` for build the project, run it as `make VERBOSE=1`, so exact compilation/linking command lines will be shown.

Comment: The problem could be that the Object Files should be Source Files in the `CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE` command. The package does successfully build now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a C++ source file with a C++ header file where the functions are defined in the CUDA source file, the CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE now looks like:

```
CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(sigma_cuda_pkg_node src/main.cpp src/main.cu ${SOURCES_SIGMA_CUDA} OPTIONS -G)
```

Don't forget to remove the -G flag (which is for debugging) to optimize performance (with the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` variable).

The project successfully builds.