# How can I build my custom CUDA library by CMake and link to it correctly?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I am trying to use cmake to build my own library. The code is finished by CUDA C/CXX. My CUDA code and CMake script are below:

The structure of the code:

```
.
├── include
│   └── Function.cuh
├── lib
│   ├── build
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   └── Function.cu
└── Test
    ├── bin
    ├── build
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── compileCode.sh
    └── src
        └── main.cu

8 directories, 6 files
```

The header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

__global__ void Function();
```

The source file:

```
#include "Function.cuh"

__global__ void Function()
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (i > 2)
        return;
    printf("Function %d\n", i);
};
```

The user's interface, i.e. `main.cu`:

```
#include "Function.cuh"

int main()
{
    Function<<<1, 3>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
};
```

The CMake file to build library

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)

project (generate_lib)

enable_language(CUDA)

set (SCRIPT_ROOT $ENV{HOME}/Desktop/cuda_custom_lib_test)

include_directories(${SCRIPT_ROOT}/include)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_CU_PATH ${SCRIPT_ROOT}/src/*.cu)

SET (CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcudafe --display_error_number")
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=3057")
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=1301")
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=3059")
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -arch=sm_60 -std=c++17 -rdc=true")

add_library (CUDA_CUSTOM_LIB_TEST_shared SHARED ${SRC_CU_PATH})
add_library(CUDA_CUSTOM_LIB_TEST_static STATIC ${SRC_CU_PATH})

set_target_properties(CUDA_CUSTOM_LIB_TEST_shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "cuda_custom_lib_test")
set_target_properties(CUDA_CUSTOM_LIB_TEST_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "cuda_custom_lib_test")

set (LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( CUDA_CUSTOM_LIB_TEST_shared ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( CUDA_CUSTOM_LIB_TEST_static ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

The CMake file to link the library to the main.cu file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (MAIN_TEST)

enable_language(CUDA)

set (SCRIPT_ROOT $ENV{HOME}/Desktop/cuda_custom_lib_test)

set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin) ## bin is the EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH

set (SRC_LIST ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cu)

include_directories(${SCRIPT_ROOT}/include)

find_library(LIBTEST libcuda_custom_lib_test.so HINTS ${SCRIPT_ROOT}/lib)
# find_library(LIBTEST libcuda_custom_lib_test.a HINTS ${SCRIPT_ROOT}/lib)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(main
    ${SRC_LIST}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( main ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( main ${LIBTEST})

SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcudafe --display_error_number")
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=3057")
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=1301")
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=3059")
SET (CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -arch=sm_60 -std=c++17")
```

I indeed succeeded to build the library with the first `CMakeLists.txt`. However, after linking the library with the second `CMakeLists.txt` to the `main.cu` file, the kernel function was not working, and nothing was printed out.

I also tried to link the `libcuda_custom_lib_test.a` to the  `main.cu` file, and I got the follow error message:

```
/home/~/Desktop/cuda_custom_lib_test/lib/libcuda_custom_lib_test.a(Function.cu.o): In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00002db8_00000000-5_Function.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xaac): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_43_tmpxft_00002db8_00000000_6_Function_cpp1_ii_83310bf0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is the problem with my CMakeLists?

Comment: If possible you should use CMake 3.18 or above, because they added many features for using CUDA. The most important changes you can also get with CMake 3.8/3.9, see [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/building-cuda-applications-cmake/) blog post.

Comment: I just saw that you already use `enable_language(CUDA)` which is only possible with CMake >=3.8, so you just need to change the `cmake_minimum_required`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Parallelism - undefined reference to \_\_cudaRegisterLinkedBinary linking error while compiling - separate compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115197/dynamic-parallelism-undefined-reference-to-cudaregisterlinkedbinary-linking)

Comment: @paleonix, I saw and downloaded the CMakeLists in the [blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/building-cuda-applications-cmake/). It compiled and worked fine. But the code was linking to the so-called `cmake_device_link.o` but not the shared library. Then I tried to link the particle test code to the library, the same problem happened again. In short, it is the  `cmake_device_link.o` making the code work, but not the compiled library.

Comment: @M.Steiner  This question cannot solve my question, because the NVCC actually generates a device code link by `-dlink`. I want to build cuda library, because my program could be very huge. When I use functions in the program (i.e. make changes in the user's interface), I have to compile the whole program again (in this process, a device link is generated by integrating all *.o files), which is very time-comsuming.

Comment: As the error message is showing, the build generated by your CMakeLists is trying to use `ld` to link here which wont work. You need to use `nvcc` here and you will also need [`CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION.html). For this reason, normally developers write host wrappers around their kernels (e..g. in `Function.cu`), such that the interface is only host code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the **first** `CMakeLists.txt`, the shared and static library can be built. Then, use `NVCC` to compile the user's interface and link to *static* library. For example, one can go to the `Test` library, then input

```
nvcc ./src/main.cu ../lib/libcuda_custom_lib_test.a -o ./bin/main -I ../include -arch=sm_60 -rdc=true
```

,
then run the code with

```
./bin/main
```

, and finally get information on the terminal

```
~/Desktop/cuda_custom_lib_test/Test$ ./bin/main
Function 0
Function 1
Function 2
```

I am not sure why this method solves the problem. But the key is that, with the static library, one does not need to use `-l`. Instead, just put the static library name (with path) behind the `main.cu`.

Since `NVCC` works well, I thought that we can use CMake to call `NVCC` to do the same thing. But I got failed. I put the `CMakeLists.txt` here. If someone can correct that, please comment.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project (MAIN_TEST)

find_package(CUDA)

set (SCRIPT_ROOT $ENV{HOME}/Desktop/cuda_custom_lib_test)

set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin) ## bin is the EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH

set (SRC_LIST ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cu)
# set (SRC_LIST ${SRC_LIST} ${SCRIPT_ROOT}/lib/libcuda_custom_lib_test.a)

include_directories(${SCRIPT_ROOT}/include)

# find_library(LIBTEST libcuda_custom_lib_test.so HINTS ${SCRIPT_ROOT}/lib)
# find_library(LIBTEST libcuda_custom_lib_test.a HINTS ${SCRIPT_ROOT}/lib)

CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(main
    ${SRC_LIST} ${SCRIPT_ROOT}/lib/libcuda_custom_lib_test.a
    OPTIONS -arch=sm_60 -std=c++17 -rdc=true
)
# target_link_libraries(main ${SCRIPT_ROOT}/lib/libcuda_custom_lib_test.a)

# set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

The error message is

```
[ 50%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main_generated_main.cu.o
Scanning dependencies of target main
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/main
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main_generated_main.cu.o: In function `main':
/home/~/Desktop/cuda_custom_lib_test/Test/src/main.cu:5: undefined reference to `Function()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main_generated_main.cu.o: In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
/tmp/tmpxft_00004857_00000000-5_main.cudafe1.stub.c:18: undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_39_tmpxft_00004857_00000000_6_main_cpp1_ii_main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:79: recipe for target '../bin/main' failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/main] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It is weird to see that the CMake insists on compiling the `main.cu` into a CXX executable, while I did not intend to use `g++`.